# Can these two definitions be proven equivalent without the axiom of choice?

Tags: set-theory

By $Map(X,Y)$, I denote the set of functions from $X$ into $Y$. Consider $Map(X,X)$, and let $f$ and $g$ be elements of $Map(X,X)$. I define a relation "$g$ is a function of $f$", iff there exists a function $h \in Map(X,X)$, such that $h$ composed with $f$ equals $g$. My original definition, however, was "if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $g(x)=g(y)$, for all $x \in X$". These two definitions can be proven equivalent with the axiom of choice. However, what happens if we don't assume choice? Can it be proven equivalent in ZF alone? And if not, is the principle equivalent to choice over ZF, or strictly weaker than choice?

Comment: Both definitions are equivalent to saying that $f$ and $g$ have the same fibres. As Eric Wofsey shows, no choice is needed to prove this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how the axiom of choice would be involved here.  Just define $h(a)$ to be the common value of $g(x)$ for all $x$ such that $f(x)=a$ (there is at most one such value of $g(x)$ by hypothesis), or define $h(a)$ arbitrarily (say, $h(a)=a$) if no such $x$ exists.